# android-NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method p()

Tags: android, debugging, crash, crashlytics, android-debug

I'm using `Crashlytics` to monitor crashes of my Android app. the following crash has been reported for some users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.mapdroid.activities.MapActivity.p()' on a null object reference
   at app.mapdroid.fragments.InfinityFragment$2.run(InfinityFragment.java:8)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

I don't understand what is `p()` method which is causing this crash. can anyone guide please?

the app has been reported to be in background state for all users with proximity on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think crashlytics is showing obfuscated code due to absence of mapping file.
[Upload mapping](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en)  file on Google Play console and crashlytics will produce sensible reports whenever new crash will be reported.

But for the current crash, you have to manually look into mapping file or wait for another crash